# Sencha 6.5 (modern) how to dynamically change the items in a menu in a title bar?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-modern, extjs6.5

Well considering a grid I create in my application:

```
    {
        xtype: 'ordergrid',
        itemId: 'ordergrid',

        titleBar: {
            shadow: false,
            items: [{
                align: 'right',
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Update status',
                stretchMenu: true,
                menu: {
                    itemId: 'status_menu',
                    defaults: {
                        handler: 'updateStatus'
                    },
                    indented: false,
                    items: [{
                        text: 'test1',
                        value: 'test1'
                    }, {
                        text: 'test2',
                        value: 'test2'
                    }, {
                        text: 'test3',
                        value: 'test4'
                    }]
                }
            }]
        },
```

With `ordergrid` being defined with:

```
extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',
xtype: 'ordergrid',
```

I wish to modify the `items` of the `menu` dynamically. I've first tried doing this through a store:

```
                menu: {
                    itemId: 'status_menu',
                    defaults: {
                        handler: 'updateStatus'
                    },
                    indented: false,
                    store: { type: 'status' }
```

Though this doesn't seem to work. Then I tried accessing this menu through a component query, during the `init` function of some controller:

```
Ext.define('BinkPortalFrontend.view.main.OrderController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    alias: 'controller.order',

    init: function () {
        console.log('..... initializing ......');
        const menus = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('ordergrid #status_menu');
        const menu = menus[0];
        menu.setItems([{
            text: 'some',
            value: 'some'
        }, {
            text: 'new',
            value: 'mew'
        }]);
    },
};
```

However this returns an error: "Cannot read property 'setItems' of undefined"
Debugging shows the obvious problem: it doesn't find any menu.

What's more, even a "catch all" query like

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('menu');
```

or

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#status_menu');
```

Shows an empty array: so what's going on? (I most definitely see the menu from its initial load).

Comment: Have you tried to get the button through ComponentQuery, then use `getMenu()`?

Answer (score 0):

There is one reason your menu is not created. Menu will created whenever button will [`tap`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#event-tap) or whenever [`getMenu()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#method-getMenu) method get called.

If you want to get your [`menu`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.menu.Menu.html) using [`Ext.ComponentQuery.query()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.ComponentQuery.html#method-query), so for this you need to do use [`initialize`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#event-initialize) event of `button` and forcefully create menu using `getMenu()` method like below :-

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Update status',
    stretchMenu: true,
    menu: {
        itemId: 'status_menu',
        indented: false,
        items: [{
            text: 'test1',
            value: 'test1'
        }, {
            text: 'test2',
            value: 'test2'
        }, {
            text: 'test3',
            value: 'test4'
        }]
    },
    listeners: {
        initialize: function(btn) {
            Ext.defer(function() {
                // This will print undefined because menu have not created  
                console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#status_menu')[0]);

                //When we use getMenu method it will create menu item  
                btn.getMenu().hide();

                // This will print menu component  
                console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#status_menu')[0]);
            }, 10)
        }
    }
}
```

Another way you can use [`getMenu()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#method-getMenu) method of `button`. It will return the `menu` component.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2dqc)**, I have created a demo using `grid`, `button` and `menu`. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                'name': 'Lisa',
                "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-111-1224"
            }, {
                'name': 'Bart',
                "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1234"
            }, {
                'name': 'Homer',
                "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1244"
            }, {
                'name': 'Marge',
                "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-222-1254"
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
            title: 'Change menu items dynamically',
            titleBar: {
                shadow: false,
                items: [{
                    align: 'right',
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Update status',
                    stretchMenu: true,
                    itemId: 'statusbtn',
                    menu: {
                        itemId: 'status_menu',
                        defaults: {
                            // handler: 'updateStatus'
                        },
                        indented: false,
                        items: [{
                            text: 'test1',
                            value: 'test1'
                        }, {
                            text: 'test2',
                            value: 'test2'
                        }, {
                            text: 'test3',
                            value: 'test4'
                        }]
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        initialize: function (btn) {
                            Ext.defer(function () {
                                // This will undefined because menu has not been created
                                console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#status_menu')[0]);

                                //When we use getMenu method it will create menu item
                                btn.getMenu().hide();

                                // This will menu component
                                console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#status_menu')[0]);
                            }, 10)
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    align: 'right',
                    text: 'Change Items',
                    handler: function (btn) {
                        var newItems = [];

                        store.each(rec => {
                            newItems.push({
                                text: rec.get('name'),
                                value: rec.get('name')
                            })
                        });
                        /*
                         *  You can also get menu using button
                         *  btn.up('titlebar').down('#statusbtn').getMenu().setItems(newItems);
                         */
                        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#status_menu')[0].setItems(newItems);
                        Ext.toast('Menu items has been change. Please check', 2000);
                    }
                }]
            },
            store: store,
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                width: 200
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                width: 250
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone',
                width: 120
            }],
            height: 200,
            layout: 'fit',
            fullscreen: true
        });
    }
});
```

For more details about component you can also see this [`ComponentManager`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.ComponentManager.html)